# Relying on Meteor.userId() for security in Meteor?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a method on the server to update a users email address. I know this will only work while users only have 1 email address but this is OK for now.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'user.updateEmail'({ email, userId }) {
    Meteor.users.update(
      { _id: userId },
      {
        $set: {
          'emails.0.address': email,
          'emails.0.verified': false,
        },
      },
    );
  },
});
```

Im calling this method from a form in a React component:

```
const formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = e.target.email.value;
    const userId = Meteor.userId();
    Meteor.call('user.updateEmail', { email, userId }, err => {
      if (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    });
  };
```

Is this insecure? Im passing the userId from the client so presumably it could be altered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. You should use `Meteor.userId()` in your method to receive the user's id. The user can't change this one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother passing the user id from the client. You can get the user id from the server itself using `Meteor.userId()`

More information:

Meteor.user() - [Get the current user record, or null if no user is logged in. A reactive data source](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user)
Meteor.userId() - [Get the current user id, or null if no user is logged in. A reactive data source](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId)
this.userId - [Access inside the publish function. The id of the logged-in user, or null if no user is logged in](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-userId)
 and [The id of the user that made this method call, or null if no user was logged in](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-userId).